# Java - Impossible Error?

Tags: java, class, compiler-errors

- When I compile my program I get `error: cannot find symbol`
- When I declare the variable I get `error: variable random is already
  defined in method` in my `getMove()` method.
- The variable that is giving me this error is my `random` variable.
- Note that all if
  statements cannot be moved around, they must remain in the order you
  see them.
- Note that I am only allowed to change `random` if `myCount == 0`.  I want to keep `random` as it's previous value otherwise.

**Here is my class code:**

```
public class Frog extends AbstractCritter
{
   private int myDirection;
   private int myCount;

   public Frog()
   {
      super('F');
      myDirection = CENTER;
      myCount = 0;
   }
   public int getMove(CritterInfo theInfo)
   {
      int result = CENTER;

      if (myCount == 0)
      {
         double random = Math.random();
      }

      if (random < 0.25)
      {
         myDirection =  NORTH;
      }
      else if (random < 0.5)
      {
         myDirection = SOUTH;
      }
      else if (random < 0.75)
      {
         myDirection = EAST;
      }
      else
      {
         myDirection = WEST;
      }
      myCount++;
      if (myCount == 3)
      {
         myCount = 0;
      }

      if (theInfo.getNeighbor(myDirection) == 'S')
      {
         result =  CENTER;
      }
      else
      {
         result = myDirection;
      }
      return result;
   }
}
```

If anything is unclear please let me know in a comment. Thank you.

Comment: `double random = Math.random();` is declared within the context of the `if (myCount == 0)` which makes it unavailable to the rest of the method, but if you declare another variable before this statement, you will get a duplicate decleration

Comment: @MadProgrammer Please see updated question.  I need it to be in the if statement because I want it to stay that value until `myCount` is 0.  Declaring it below `int result = CENTER;` also does not work, it gives an error.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Please see my response to MadProgrammer.

Comment: BUT the variable is local to the  method, so when the method exists, it's value it lost!?

Comment: Move the `if-else-if` block using the `random` into the block where `random` is declared.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you!  I made random a private field and now my program compiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you define `random` inside your first `if` statement, so it's only visible inside that statement. Instead, try making it a class variable: below `private int myCount;` add `private double random;` and inside your constructor, add `random = Math.random();` to initialize it.

Comment: The problem with that is the fact that I only want to change random when `myCount == 0`

Comment: In that case, then right below `int result = CENTER;`, just add `double random;`, and then remove `double` from your first if block so it just reads `random = Math.random();`

Comment: That gives me `error: variable random might not have been initialized` for `if (random < 0.25)`  [Here](http://prntscr.com/7y7s7a) is a screenshot.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. You will have to initialize `random` to some value. You can set it in your `Frog` class instead, right after you initialize `myCount = 0` (make sure you declare it at the beginning of your class, too, right after `private int myCount;`, add `private double random;`

Comment: I see now, I needed a private field because a local variable wouldn't be used outside of the method.  Please update your answer so I can mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Just move `double random = Math.random();` after this line `int result = CENTER;`

You have declared random inside `if` statement and it's scope ends with the `if` statement.

How about this, if you want to use Random number if `myCount == 0`.

```
  int result = CENTER;

  double random = 0.0;
  if (myCount == 0)
  {
     random = Math.random();
  }
```

Comment: Usually I would do this, but I need to be able to keep using a random value and only change it when the counter is 0.  [This](http://prntscr.com/7y7pkx) screenshot shows the assignment with a description of what I mean underlined in red.